# I'm working on a project for physics, however whenever I try to use multiplication my answers are very wrong no matter the input

Tags: c, gcc, printf, codeblocks

Here is my code, it is far from finished but I cant progress much further before I work this out. No errors are showing up, however I have the warning - 
"format '%i' expects argument of type 'int' but argument 2 has type 'int*'

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<math.h>

    main()   
    {
        int m_1;
        int m_2;
        printf("This program will take two particles, and present a collision between them.\n");
        printf("Values for base characteristics of these particles will be given by you.\n");
        printf("Enter 2 values for mass, separated by a comma.\n");
        scanf("\n%i,%i",&m_1,&m_2);

        int u_1;
        int u_2;
        int momentum1;
        int momentum2;
        int momentumtotal;

        momentum1 = m_1 * u_1;
        momentum2 = m_2 * u_2;
        momentumtotal = momentum1+momentum2;
        printf("Initial momentum - P1 = %i\n",&momentum1);

        printf("Initial momentum - P2 = %i\n", &momentum2);
    }
```

Comment: Drop the ampersand in `printf`'s argument. `momentum1`, not `&momentum1`

Comment: This looks like C code. Are you sure this is C++ code? Do you name your source files *.cpp and compiler with a C++ compiler?

Comment: the warning is to the point (pun intended). `&momentum1` is a `int*`, but you want to print an `int`

Comment: Thank you, that was it, I was under the impression that the ampersand was used to call a specific variable, I clearly have a lot to learn yet.

Comment: You need to check the return value from `scanf("\n%i,%i",&m_1,&m_2);` which should be `2`. I would also simplify it to `scanf("%i %i", &m_1, &m_2);` and don't enter a comma between numbers.

Comment: `&momentum1`,`&momentum2`-->`momentum1`,`momentum2`

Comment: regarding: `momentum1 = m_1 * u_1;` and ` momentum2 = m_2 * u_2;`  The local variable `u_1` and `u_2` are not initialized  so using them in the multiplication results in undefined behavior.

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("\n%i,%i",&m_1,&m_2);`  Should always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful. Note: the `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful 'input format conversion' specifiers (or EOF).  Suggest: `if( scanf("\n%i,%i",&m_1,&m_2) != 2 ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for two momentum values failed\n" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: OT: regarding: `#include<math.h>`  Nothing in this header file is being used.  It is a very poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used.  Suggest removing that statement